# Problem getting messages after loading html between main and renderer

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm building an Electron application and I'm stuck with the following problem.
I'm getting information using a socket from an apparatus, and It was working fine. I wanted to change the html of the page if the program gets a type of message, so basically I used the loadUrl method, but then, after sending a message to the renderer process I't seems like it's not being received.

My code:

```
photoViewOn = false;
...
app.on('ready', function(){
    // Create new window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      backgroundColor: '#000000',
      fullscreen : true, 
      frame : false,
      icon : __dirname + "/res/logo.png",
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration : true
      }
    });


    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    // Load html in window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'bigNames.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes:true,
    }))...)

function HTMLupdate(msg) {
  mainWindow && mainWindow.webContents.send('update', msg);


var server = socketBuilder('localhost', '7777',  {
   message: (msg, rinfo) => {
     try {
      console.log(`server got: ${msg} from ${rinfo.address}:${rinfo.port}`);
      var infoMap = processCyrano(msg);
      //if (infoMap["Com"] === "")
      if (infoMap != null) {
        if (infoMap["Com"] === "INFO") {
          if (photoViewOn) {
            photoViewOn = false;
            bigNamesView();
          }
          console.log("Inside Infomap");
          console.log(`Left Fencer: ${infoMap["LeftName"]}`);
          console.log(`Right Fencer: ${infoMap["RightName"]}`);
          HTMLupdate(infoMap);
        }
      }
    }

    catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error ${error}`);
    }


   },
   error: (err) => {
     console.log(`server error:\n${err.stack}`);
     server.close();
   },
   listen: () => {
     const address = server.address();
     console.log(`server listening ${address.address}:${address.port}`);
   }
});


function photoView() {
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'photos.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes:true,
  }));
}


function bigNamesView() {
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'bigNames.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes:true,
  }));
}

function processCyrano(msg) {

  try {

    let stripMsg = msg.toString().split("%");
    let info = {};
    let compInfo = stripMsg[0].split("|");
    console.log(compInfo);

    if(compInfo[2] === "INFO" || compInfo[2] === "DISP") {
      let firstFencerInfo = stripMsg[1].split("|")
      let secondFencerInfo = stripMsg[2].split("|")
      info.Protocol = compInfo[1];
      info.Com = compInfo[2]
      info.Piste = compInfo[3]
      info.Compe = compInfo[4];
      info.Phase = compInfo[5];
      info.PoulTab = compInfo[6];
      info.Match = compInfo[7];
      info.Round = compInfo[8];
      info.RightId = firstFencerInfo[1];
      info.RightName = firstFencerInfo[2];
      info.RightNat = firstFencerInfo[3];
      info.Rscore = firstFencerInfo[4];
      info.Rstatus = firstFencerInfo[5];
      info.RYcard = firstFencerInfo[6];
      info.Rrcard = firstFencerInfo[7];
      info.Rlight = firstFencerInfo[8];
      info.RWlight = firstFencerInfo[9];
      info.LeftId = secondFencerInfo[1];
      info.LeftName = secondFencerInfo[2];
      info.LeftNat = secondFencerInfo[3];
      info.Lscore = secondFencerInfo[4];
      info.Lstatus = secondFencerInfo[5];
      info.LYcard = secondFencerInfo[6];
      info.Lrcard = secondFencerInfo[7];
      info.Llight = secondFencerInfo[8];
      info.LWlight = secondFencerInfo[9];
      lastMatch = info;
      return info;
    }

    else if (compInfo[2] === "PHOTO-NEXT") {
      console.log("Photo-Next received");
      photoViewOn = true;
      photoView();
    }

    else if (compInfo[2] === "PHOTO-SCORE") {
      console.log("Photo-score received");
      photoViewOn = true;
      photoView();
    }

    else if (compInfo[2] === "PHOTO-STOP") {
      console.log("Photo-Stop received");
      return lastMatch;
    }
    return null;
  }
  catch (error) {
    //Avoid empty messages of the protocol
    console.log(`Error ${error}`);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Basically my attempt is, if I get a "Photo-Score" message, call photoView() (this works fine), and if "Photo-Stop" is received, call bigNamesView() and start sending information agoin using HTMLUpdate(msg), but it doesn't work for me. Any clue why this is happening?
Note that I remove some irrelevant code. Thanks.

Comment: hi did you check my answer again i edited it next day

Answer (score 0):

hi   my  friend      you problem  is  that  `lastMatch = info`  only happens  inside

`if(compInfo[2] === "INFO" || compInfo[2] === "DISP") {`

So Only When  `"Photo-Stop"` is received    then you return `lastMatch`
.

inside the code your logic says only when we receive `INFO` call bigNamesView()

but  you want only when we receive `PHOTO-STOP`  call bigNamesView()

.

**Also about the loadurl   method**   you call `mainWindow.webContents.send('update', msg);` in HTMLupdate  immediately  you should wait for event  did-finish-load then  call send update msg

```
win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    HTMLupdate(infoMap);
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is more a comment than an actual answer. Also I think this has nothing to do with my question about why loadUrl() is changing the connection between the main and render process.

Answer (score 0):

In your server you have the condition

```
if (photoViewOn) {bigNamesView()}
```

but in function processCyrano your condition for 'PHOTO-STOP' doesn't set photoViewOn to true.

```
else if (compInfo[2] === "PHOTO-STOP") {
      console.log("Photo-Stop received");
      return lastMatch;
    }
```

Change to

```
else if (compInfo[2] === "PHOTO-STOP") {
      console.log("Photo-Stop received");
      photoViewOn = true;
      return lastMatch;
    }
```